# any way to track an application

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, executable, execute-command

I have a software which when I go its directory path in terminal I run ./myprogram and my application start so I want to know how to understand which files are reading by my program  which is not related to my program? for example suppose my program read files from system how to know which are this files?

Comment: `strace command`

Comment: @AvinashRaj would you expand your seggestion please

Comment: yes i flag it to duplicate I can not delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `lsofs` you can trace what files are accessed by a process. I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but it would be something like this:

```
lsofs | grep myprogram
```